# How to query datomic for all datoms in a particular partition?

Tags: datomic

In Datomic query language how can I write a query to return all datoms in a particular partition? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally can't really use a Datalog query for that, because it would require to traverse all the datoms of the database, which Datalog won't let you do.

Given any entity id, you can retrieve it's partition by calling the [`part`](http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/#datomic.api/part) function of the Peer library.

You can then use a [filter](http://docs.datomic.com/filters.html) on your database to have a view of only those datoms. Here's a Clojure example:

```
(defn part-db 
  "Given a db and a partition entity id, 
  returns a view of the db with only the datoms which entities are of this partition."
  [db part]
  (d/filter db (fn [_ ^Datom datom] 
                 (-> datom .e d/part (= part))
                 )))
```

To find out the entity id of your partition from it's name (e.g `:my.partitions/part1`), you can for example resolve it as an Entity:

```
(def my-part-id (:db/id (d/entity mydb :my.partitions/part1)))
```

From here, you can:

1. List all the datoms of your database through the index: `(d/datoms (part-db mydb my-part-id) :eavt)`
2. Query the filtered database using Datalog.
3. ... whatever else you do with a database value!

Note that if you really want to get *all* the datoms, you may want to do this on a history database.